# Binding a Datagrid using a value of a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a WPF application. 
I am trying to bind a datagrid by querying my sql database using a value that is displayed in a TextBox. 
At the moment the TextBox is displaying a selected item from a previous window.

I am looking to display the date and amount from my payments table where the name is equal to the selected item displayed in my TextBox.

```
     private void BinddatagridPaid()
     {
         SqlConnection sqlCon2 =
             new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = ODHRAN\SQLEXPRESS; Initial 
         Catalog = FitnessWorks; Integrated Security = True")
         sqlCon2.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
         string Value = textBox1.Text;

         cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT Payments.DatePaid, Payments.Amount FROM 
         Payments Where Payments.Name=@Value";
         cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", Value);

         cmd2.Connection = sqlCon2;
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
         DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("AmountPaid");

         da.Fill(dt2);

         DataGridPaid.ItemsSource = dt2.DefaultView;
     }
```

Here is the code from how i am populating the textbox:

```
       private void DataGrid2_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, 
       MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
          MemberSesh ms = new MemberSesh();
          DataGrid gd1 = (DataGrid)sender;
          DataRowView row_selected = gd1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
          if (row_selected != null)
           {
            ms.textBox1.Text = row_selected["Name"].ToString();
            ms.textBox2.Text = row_selected["Cost"].ToString();
           }
          ms.ShowDialog();
        }
```

I am unable to use the value in my TextBox to query the database and fill the datagrid.

Comment: please clearly mention what is the problem you facing ?

Comment: I am unable to use the value in my TextBox to query the database and fill the datagrid.

Comment: you mean `string Value = textBox1.Text;` is not fetching right value ?

Comment: Correct, Is this because of the way i have used     row_selected    to display the Name in textBox1?

Comment: where is that textBox1 instance coming from and where its text property is set ?

Comment: what is `MemberSesh` I see textBox is memeber of this class. I see some disconnect here

Comment: looks these textboxes are part of `MemberSesh` different form, right ? So what textBox1 is in `BinddatagridPaid` method ?

Comment: I have a Window called Memberships, this has a datagrid that displays the details of current members, when i double click on a row it then opens up a new window called MemberSesh and uses row_selected to display the name of the member from the previous datagrid in textBox1. I then want to use textBox1 to query my database and display results in a datagrid.

Comment: got your point. But for this to work that textbox instance across two forms should be shared, right ? do u agree ?

Comment: Yes, How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access Parent Form `textBox1` instance to set text property in `MemberSesh` form.

You can access parent form using `this.Parent` property of new form. Which you first need to cast and then use `textBox1` member on that.